# How many different undirected, planar, connected graphs are there where every edge is in a 3-cycle?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, planar-graphs

I am interested in undirected, planar, connected graphs where every edge is in a 3-cycle. If there are 4 vertices then, up to isomorphism,  there are two such graphs.

[image]

How many are there for 5 vertices?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: You might want to add context to your question in order to avoid getting it closed.

Comment: @ronno Are you also counting the empty subset? Cause I only found $6$.

Comment: @Aig yeah I missed planar

Comment: @Aig Thank you for confirming it is 6

Answer (score 2):

There are really not that many graphs with $5$-vertices up to isomorphism, so this is really just a matter of checking them out. Here are all $34$ of them:

[image]

$K_5$ is the only non-planar of the bunch and its easy to get rid the unconnected ones.

[image]

Comment: Is the final answer  6?